# Walker $args receive object on local and array on production

Tags: wordpress, wp-nav-walker

Have an issue on local machine `print_r($args)` give me  `stdClass Object`, on production i receive `array` instead. I Check PHP version and WordPress version, they are the same. What can affect the format received?
my code

```
function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ){ //li a span
        
        $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat("\t",$depth) : '';
        
        $dir=get_template_directory_uri();
        $li_attributes = '';
        $class_names = $value = '';
        
        $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
        echo '<pre>';
            print_r($args);
        echo '</pre>';
        $classes[] = ($args->walker->has_children) ? 'dropdown' : '';
        $classes[] = ($item->current || $item->current_item_ancestor) ? 'active' : '';
        $classes[] = 'menu-item-' . $item->ID;
        if( $depth && $args->walker->has_children ){
            $classes[] = 'dropdown-submenu';
        }
        
        $class_names =  join(' ', apply_filters('nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args ) );

        $class_names = ' class="' . esc_attr($class_names) . '"';
        
        $id = apply_filters('nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-'.$item->ID, $item, $args);
        $id = strlen( $id ) ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';
        
        $output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $value . $class_names . $li_attributes . '>';
        
        $attributes = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="' . esc_attr($item->attr_title) . '"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target ) ? ' target="' . esc_attr($item->target) . '"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn ) ? ' rel="' . esc_attr($item->xfn) . '"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url ) ? ' href="' . esc_attr($item->url) . '"' : '';
        
        $attributes .= ( $args->walker->has_children ) ? ' class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"' : '';
        
        $item_output = $args->before;
        $item_output .= '<a' . $attributes . '>';
        $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
        $dropdown_icons="";

        if ( $depth >= 0 && $args->walker->has_children ) {
            $dropdown_icons=' <span class="dropdown-toggle-button">';
            if ($depth > 0) {
                $dropdown_icons .= '<svg class="angle-right">
                    <use xlink:href="#angle-right-solid"></use>
                </svg>';
            }
            $dropdown_icons .= '</span></a>';  //TODO INline 2 diff svg
        } 
        else {
            $dropdown_icons.= '</a>';
        }
        $item_output .= $dropdown_icons;

            
        $item_output .= $args->after;
    
        $output .= apply_filters ( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );

        
    }
```

Update V1

Production output

```
<pre>Array
(
    [depth] =&gt; 0
    [show_date] =&gt; 
    [date_format] =&gt; F j, Y
    [child_of] =&gt; 0
    [exclude] =&gt; 
    [title_li] =&gt; 
    [echo] =&gt; 
    [authors] =&gt; 
    [sort_column] =&gt; menu_order, post_title
    [link_before] =&gt; 
    [link_after] =&gt; 
    [item_spacing] =&gt; preserve
    [walker] =&gt; Walker_Nav_Primary Object
        (
            [tree_type] =&gt; Array
                (
                    [0] =&gt; post_type
                    [1] =&gt; taxonomy
                    [2] =&gt; custom
                )

            [db_fields] =&gt; Array
                (
                    [parent] =&gt; menu_item_parent
                    [id] =&gt; db_id
                )

            [max_pages] =&gt; 1
            [has_children] =&gt; 
        )

    [menu_id] =&gt; primary-menu
    [menu_class] =&gt; menu
    [container] =&gt; div
    [before] =&gt; 
    [after] =&gt; 
    [menu] =&gt; 
    [container_class] =&gt; 
    [container_id] =&gt; 
    [container_aria_label] =&gt; 
    [fallback_cb] =&gt; wp_page_menu
    [items_wrap] =&gt; <ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s nav-menu">%3$s</ul>
    [theme_location] =&gt; menu-1
    [hierarchical] =&gt; 0
    [has_children] =&gt; 
)
</pre>
```

and error `Attempt to read property "walker" on array in`

Local

```
<pre>stdClass Object
(
    [menu] =&gt; WP_Term Object
        (
            [term_id] =&gt; 2
            [name] =&gt; Menu 1
            [slug] =&gt; menu-1
            [term_group] =&gt; 0
            [term_taxonomy_id] =&gt; 2
            [taxonomy] =&gt; nav_menu
            [description] =&gt; 
            [parent] =&gt; 0
            [count] =&gt; 20
            [filter] =&gt; raw
        )

    [container] =&gt; div
    [container_class] =&gt; 
    [container_id] =&gt; 
    [container_aria_label] =&gt; 
    [menu_class] =&gt; menu
    [menu_id] =&gt; primary-menu
    [echo] =&gt; 1
    [fallback_cb] =&gt; wp_page_menu
    [before] =&gt; 
    [after] =&gt; 
    [link_before] =&gt; 
    [link_after] =&gt; 
    [items_wrap] =&gt; <ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s nav-menu">%3$s</ul>
    [item_spacing] =&gt; preserve
    [depth] =&gt; 0
    [walker] =&gt; Walker_Nav_Primary Object
        (
            [tree_type] =&gt; Array
                (
                    [0] =&gt; post_type
                    [1] =&gt; taxonomy
                    [2] =&gt; custom
                )

            [db_fields] =&gt; Array
                (
                    [parent] =&gt; menu_item_parent
                    [id] =&gt; db_id
                )

            [max_pages] =&gt; 1
            [has_children] =&gt; 1
        )

    [theme_location] =&gt; menu-1
)
</pre>
```

I duplicate whole site via duplicater and don't change menu setting, only add menu links

Comment: Can you post the output for the `print_r` in both cases.   My hunch is that on local you  have a menu set which would should return `stdClass Object`. but maybe in prod no menu is set and returns `array` because you set the default to an `array`.  have you tried `null` as the default (which is what WP docs show) and still get an array in prod?

Comment: @mikerojas i update my post(add output data) and i duplicate whole site before

Answer (score 2):

I got this same issue. The problem was, that somehow during website migration menu lost his "Display settings" (Appearance -> Menu -> Menu we are talking about).

So please login into migrated WP and reset it. Then Walker will return proper Object not Array.